# Probability of various systems

Tags: probability

[image]

For these systems, I'm given the information $Pr(W_1)=Pr(W_2)=Pr(W_3)=Pr(W_4)=Pr(W_5)=p$.
I'm also told to let $W_i$ be the event that component i functions.

I found the probability that system A functions, in terms of $p$ to be $(1-(1-p)^2)(1-(1-p)^3)$, and the probability of system B functions to be $(p^2)-(p^2)(1-(1-p)^3)$. So, are these correct, and if so, how would I find the value of $p$ for which the difference in reliability is at a maximum.

Comment: Please format your question using [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Assuming that for the parallel subsystems, one functioning component is enough, you would get $A_B = p^2 ( 1 - (1-p)^3)$ for System B.

Comment: That's what I have, so how would i then find the difference in reliability.

Comment: To find the $p$ that maximizes the difference, just take the derivative of the difference with respect to $p$ and set it to zero, i.e. $\frac{\text d}{\text dp} (A_A - A_B) = 0$.